# Deconvolution of system response in Python/Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing, convolution, deconvolution

I had two sets of data, the output function of the system (time series with a length of 1292 entries) and the transfer function (similar to a gaussian with a length of 681 entries). I would like to calculate the input function(unknown) using deconvolution.

I tried calculating the FFT for each function and then the inverse of the division of the two ffts:

Cin  = F^-1 [F(Cout)]/[F(E)]

however FFT of the transfer function seems to be zero everywhere and the resulting recovered signal have a lot of noise.
I also tried Wiener deconvolution, but once again, if I calculate the convolution of the recovered signal with the transfer function I don't obtain the output function.

- For the signals I'm using which is the most appropriate method? (FFT, SciPy convolve, Wiener)
- Do I need to "zero-pad" the transfer function to match the length of the output function?
- Since the deconvolution process is susceptible to noise, Do I need to filter the signals (before/after)?
- there is similar code in matlab or python that I could refer to?

Here the output of my code with the wiener method (output in blue, transfer in red, recovered input in green and convolution of recovered input and transfer (purple):

[image: wiener method output]

and the code for the wiener deconvolution:

```
#import data
data = pandas.read_csv("data/hetre20mod.csv")
x = data.Time

#normalize data
norm = (data.CO-data.CO.min()) / (data.CO.max()-data.CO.min())

# transfer function
length = 681
pe = 27
ttau = 203
ao = rtdpy.AD_oo(tau=ttau, peclet=pe, dt=1, time_end=length)
rtd = ao.exitage

#zero pad transfer function
kernel = np.hstack((rtd, np.zeros(len(norm) - len(rtd))))

#wiener deconvolution
lambd = 0.00035
H = np.fft.fft(kernel)
deconv = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(norm)*np.conj(H)/(H*np.conj(H) + lambd**2)))


recovered = np.convolve(deconv, kernel, mode='same') 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(4, 4))
ax[0][0].plot(x, norm, 'b', label="experimental", lw=3)
ax[0][1].plot(x, kernel, 'r', label="transfer", lw=3)
ax[1][0].plot(x, deconv, 'g', label="treated", lw=3)
ax[1][1].plot(x, recovered, 'm', label="both", lw=3)
ax[1][1].plot(x, norm, 'b',label="both", lw=3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Remember that anything you do through the FFT has the implied assumption of periodicity of the signal. I would zero-pad the signal to double its size  to avoid any effects of that. And yes, you then need to zero-pad the transfer function. Please post the code you used, so we can point out what the issue is.

Comment: I just add the code for the wiener deconvolution. So I need to zero pad both signals?

Comment: Why do you apply `np.fft.ifft` twice?

Comment: i just change that line to:  `deconv = np.real(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(norm)*np.conj(H)/(H*np.conj(H) + lambd**2)))` and in the verification I changed convolution mode to full.

Comment: Did that help? Is your output closer to what you expect now?

Comment: It is closer... however there seems to be a problem with the beginning and the end of the recovered signal, maybe because of the padding?  [see the image](https://imgur.com/OCjjmcf)

Comment: I'd expect a shift, because the FFT takes the origin to be the first element of the array, but `np.convolve' likely sets it in the middle of the array. Zero padding should work well with your signal and kernel though.

Comment: Even if I zero pad the original signal and the kernel to whatever length I'm still obtaining one part of the recovered signal at the end.

Comment: Yep, that's a shift. Remember the FFT assumes periodicity of the signal. So you can use a circular shift to shift the signal to wherever you think it's meaningful to have it.